# Two users edits collapsed under one edit log

Tags: bug, edits

I edited the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847588/903011) to a question (the question is mine, the answer is not), to fix a typo (my typo, actually, quoted from the question).

While editing, I received a prompt about the fact that an edit was done to the answer (by the answerer). I finished my edit and submitted it. The log is

[image]

This log suggests that the bottom modification (the long one, shortened to "reactive") is mine - while it is not. I only modified "member" in the quote.

Is such a collapse of edits expected?